# How to Parse syntax Highlighting In react I'm using tiptap, lowlight js (for syntax highlighting), react-html-parser)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tiptap, html-react-parser

My code

```
 <DefaultBlogLayout imgSeo={thumbnail} title={title} desc={meta}>
      {thumbnail ? (
        <div className='relative aspect-video'>
          <Image
            src={thumbnail}
            alt={title}
            fill
            style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }}
          />
        </div>
      ) : null}

      <div className='flex items-center justify-between py-2'>
        {tags.map((t, i) => (
          <span key={i}>#{t}</span>
        ))}

        <span>{getFullDate(createdAt)}</span>
        <span>{getDateDistance(createdAt)}</span>
      </div>

      <div className='prose pros-lg max-w-full mx-auto'>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        {parse(content)}
      </div>
    </DefaultBlogLayout>
```

I want to parse content that includes syntax highlighting using Tiptap.js and Lowlight.js. The content looks like this

```
content : <pre><code>const a = () =&gt;{\r\n return a\r\n}</code></pre>
```

It worked using the TITAP plugin on the admin page, but when I tried using it with React-HTML-Parser on the blog page, it didn't work."
I follow this tutorial https://tiptap.dev/examples/syntax-highlighting

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more where the issue lays and what error you get? 
Would also be sufficient with a bit more code here to understand the context.

Comment: I use syntax highlighting  using lowlights.js and tiptap,js with the syntax highlighting its work on tiptap component using the titap plugin, the problem is when i want to render it on my blog component using the react-html-parser the highlighting is not working  the content like this `<pre><code>const a = () =&gt;{\r\n return a\r\n}</code></pre>` after i parse the content like this `<pre>
<code> const a = () =>{return a}
</code` I think my issue  could be due to the that html-react-parser does not parse the syntax highlighting generated by lowlight

Comment: Is there any way to parse it?

Comment: Looks like you figured out your issue. The syntax is not preserved in the html and will never be. On the blog you need to make sure you can style and handle the <code> tags. Best of luck